# Java do method while JToggleButton is pressed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

**Objective**

I am trying to achieve code that will call upon a method for the time the `JToggleButton` in Swing is pressed down. The `MainCode.intGenerate` method, which returns an `List<Integer>`, takes in a`List<Integer>`.

**Restrictions**

Random_gen_Button is declared as such and is unchangeable due to NetBeans guarding it. I can change it using notepad to open but It is not allowing me to change it for a reason so I shall not.

```
private JToggleButton RANDOMGENBUTTON;
```

**Code**

```
private void RANDOMGENBUTTONActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    if(RANDOMGENBUTTON.isSelected()) {
        EXITBUTTON.setEnabled(false);
        List<Integer> INPUTLIST = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(RANDOMGENBUTTON.isSelected()) {
            INPUTLIST = MainCode.intGenerate(INPUTLIST);
        }
    }else {
        EXITBUTTON.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**Possible Solution**

I think this should be achievable with another Thread but I am not sure how to do this.

**The Error**

This code does not work because it freezes the GUI, I cannot press on the JToggle Button again resulting in an infinite loop.

**Edit**

**intGenerate()**

```
public static List<Integer> intGenerate(List<Integer> INLIST) {
        Random Rand = new Random();
        int RANDOMNUM = Rand.nextInt((9999999 - 1000000) + 1) + 1000000;
        if(INLIST.isEmpty()) {
            INLIST.add(randomNum);
        }else {
            while(INLIST.contains(randomNum)==true) {
                RANDOMNUM = Rand.nextInt((9999999 - 1000000) + 1) + 1000000;
            }
            INLIST.add(RANDOMNUM);
        }
        return INLIST;
```

Comment: It's an infinite loop because you don't de-select it. It's always selected thus dragging on the loop

Comment: `Random_gen_Button.isSelected()` this piece of code will always reflect `true`. So, Your loop will never terminate. this may cause of infinite-loop.

Thank You.

Comment: please post `generate_int()` method definition to clearify what exactly you try to implement in this method ??

Comment: @AndrewL. I cannot de-select it that is what I am trying to solve

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I wish I could but this is the Minimal version hence the seemingly useless and obtuse code to really only generate an integer. I will try to implement Java nomenclature in the code supplied.

Comment: @subado512, you misunderstand what MVCE stands for. You really should read the link posted by Andrew. Asking questions here will become much more pleasant/effective after you do.

Comment: *Random_gen_Button is declared as such and is unchangeable due to netbeans guarding it.* You should get to know your IDE. NB does allow you to edit guarded sections via Design tab.

Comment: Like Radiodef suggested, your problem will have to be solved with two threads - the Event Dispatch Thread (the GUI thread which you are already using) and another one, controlled by EDT. Your GUI is freezing because you are blocking EDT with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`java.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the *other thread* that periodically tells your component to update itself. In the example below, the timer's listener updates the button's text when the button is selected or the button's model says it's pressed.

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38051563/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private final Random r = new Random();

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton("0000");
        f.add(button);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        Timer t = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (button.isSelected() | button.getModel().isPressed()) {
                    button.setText(String.valueOf(r.nextInt(9000) + 1000));
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}
```

As an aside, don't let the GUI editor dictate your design.